# Using global function in C for a timer?

Tags: c, timer

I want to write a function in C that runs on a timer independently of other functions.  I don't want this timer to stop when other functions are doing work.  How can I do this?

Comment: Hmm, I read this differently than what Gunner and ayush has.  Are you trying to time your application as they suggest?  Or are you trying to have a recurring function called repeatedly after some amount of time?

Comment: d reply given by ayush n gunner ll solve the problem :) thaks so much every1 u guyz rock :)

Answer (score 0):

use `time.h` and make your own function something like [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2169.htm)

Comment: @samruddhi: if you got your answer then accept one..either mine or Gunner's..else people wont be useful to you in future ..also this would help someone in future who has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the Time value in the global variable at the entry point, that is immediately after main. After that, whenever you need to know the current program execution time, you can get it by subtracting this Time Value from the time at that instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

If you want a function to execute exactly on an interval (i.e. without jitter or delay), you need to use some kind of interrupt handler. If you are using the difference between two timestamps to determine when to call your function, your function call could be delayed indefinitely depending on the code that executes before the second timestamp is read. This is usually not desired behavior.

Perhaps it's easier to explain with a contrived example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void f() { // do something stupid and time-consuming
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 65535; ++i)
        for(j = 0; j < 65535; ++j);
} 

int main() {
    time_t t0, t1;
    t0 = time(NULL);
    f(); // waste time
    t1 = time(NULL);
    printf("time elapsed: %ld\n", t1 - t0);
}
```

On my machine this takes 11 seconds.